# In MySQL why isn't my NULL value being compared to correctly?

Tags: mysql, select, null

**I have the following table**

```
Select * from Peeps
Id Name Age 
1  Sam  16
2  John NULL


Select 
Name, 
Age,
(If Age=NULL,1,0) AS Z
from peeps;
```

**Results:**

```
+------+------+---+
| name | age  | Z |
+------+------+---+
| Sam  |   16 | 0 |
| John | NULL | 0 |
+------+------+---+
```

**Desired Results**

```
+------+------+---+
| name | age  | Z |
+------+------+---+
| Sam  |   16 | 0 |
| John | NULL | 1 |
+------+------+---+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Select 
Name, 
Age,
(If Age IS NULL,1,0) AS Z
from peeps;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead:

```
IF Age IS NULL
```

Using NULL will actually represent the null value, whereas "NULL" will act as a string with the letters N-U-L-L in it. Not the same at all.

Final query:

```
SELECT Name, 
       Age,
       (IF Age IS NULL, 1, 0) AS Z
  FROM peeps
```